# Deploy failed because of Metadata.Operation.retrieve

Tags: apex, deployment, metadata

everyone! I have following part of code:

[image]

When I validate code during deployment I get errors. Errors are - 'System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0' on line 77. When I try to use this code using an anonymous block, the accountLayout gets the first component. But during deployment, it seems like Metadata.Layout isn't visible. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It seems like the layout name issue. Please check if the variable `LAYOUT_NAME` has proper value, if it has, also, check if the layout is present with that name.

Comment: Yeah, I've already checked it previously. Everything is correct. But a mistake occurs. Maybe there are some restrictions to work with metadata? Especially when you deploy apex which works such way?

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Metadata.Metadata> layouts = Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout,  new List<String> {LayoutName});
```

"LayoutName" in the above code is a string that is set to the name of the desired layout. This is successful in most cases, such as when seeking information for:

1. Standard object layouts
2. Local custom object layouts
3. Packaged layouts for packaged objects

When setting LayoutName in the call, the general form, as you may be aware, is:

[object API name]-[layout namespace]__[Layout plain English name]

with of course no __ or namespace in the second part if the layout is local.

Successful examples include:

**Standard objects:**

Account-Account Layout

**Local custom objects:**

MyLocalObject__c-Locally defined object (Sales) Layout

**Object and Layout from a managed package:**

iair__Ticket__c-iair__Ticket Layout

It is possible that you won't be able to retrieve any results (layouts.size() = 0) in some corner cases specifically when seeking locally defined layouts for packaged objects (There is a [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008fw0QAA) around this and certainly limitations with Metadata.Operations class)

It is worth checking if you are able to retrieve the layout for the given layout name via Metadata API in both the source and destination orgs and validate if you are able to retrieve the same layout via Apex Metadata.Operations class

If you are still experiencing the issue I recommend raising an Investigation with [Salesforce Support](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workcom_contact_support.htm&language=en_us)